# PG::CONNECTION BAD connecting to pgAdminIII cloud 9 IDE

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, cloud9-ide, pgadmin

New to web development.  Trying to connect and register new server for pgAdminIII.  (using cloud 9 ide)..

I get this error when viewing in the browser..

```
_PG::CONNECTION BAD _
could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on 
"localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? 
could not connect to server: Connection 
refused Is the server running on host "localhost" 
(127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432
```

PS. trying to access via new user "ubuntu" SUPERUSER created..

How can I fix this?

PPS. On cloud 9's community forum, an employee says.. 
"*Only ports 8080, 8081 and 8082 are open for workspaces so if you want to access the DB externally you'll need to run it on one of these ports. Make sure you can access it with curl from a local terminal and ensure it's listening on 0.0.0.0 not 127.0.0.1, as the latter only allows local connections.*"

Lastly, their ide comes with postgres installed, all I needed to do, was set it up..

How do I use the above info while trying to register the new server in order to use the gui?

Let me know if I need to include anything else.

Thanks.

Comment: found any solution?

Answer (score 1):

You should enable `postgresql` service by performing `sudo service postgresql start`.

After enabling, you can access the console using `sudo sudo -u postgres psql` and `CREATE ROLE ubuntu LOGIN REPLICATION CREATEDB CREATEROLE SUPERUSER;` to allow Rails take advantage of your database.

Rails also complains about template read error after creating ubuntu role.

To fix the template error, read up on [this](https://gist.github.com/rodrigoargumedo/bd0721130208cf5ff13d).

You should get PostgreSQL server up and running in no time. Happy coding!

**Edit**:

You should **only** use `localhost` for local and system resources (i.e. `psql`, etc.) while `0.0.0.0` is for everything else like running Rails or Apache server.

Comment: Hey now when I try to get on database, I get the following error (The server doesn't accept connections: the connection library reports 
could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address (0x00002741/10049) Is the server running on host "0.0.0.0" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 8081?)  Sorry for the length..  BTW your answer helped clear up the mess with the views; I could now see my home page.. Thanks.

Comment: I think you should try 127.0.0.1 for internal connections. 0.0.0.0:[8080,8081,8082] are useful for applications that are talking externally, but for internal connections, like the database (which is used exclusively by your rails server) should be hosted on `localhost` using whichever port you desire.

Comment: I tried that.. when I try to open up the schema in pgadmin, it asks me to connect to server, where I then add localhost and ubuntu as user.. (followed this guide [postgres](https://github.com/JohnnyBurst/c9_sqlite3_to_pg) in order to create superuser ubuntu).  However, when I try to sign on, it says fatal connection failed, and databases don't exist; so, there is no connection. ps. I made sure that in the server and in database.yml, the passwords matched.  ***All the information I followed is in the readme section of the link..**  Thanks